# How to add a Substrate token created with a smart contract to my wallet? What wallet can I use for testing in a local environment?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-contracts-node, polkadot-js-extension

I created a token on the Substrate chain using a smart contract and I am now trying to add it to my wallet. However, when I enter the contract address into the "Import a token" section of the wallet, I get an error message saying that the contract address is not valid. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to proceed. Additionally, I'm not sure which wallet I can use to test the token in a local environment. Can anyone provide guidance on how to add a Substrate token created with a smart contract to my wallet, and recommend a wallet that I can use for testing in a local environment? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: ink! smart contract or Solidity smart contract?

Comment: @AlexBean ink! smart contract

Comment: @Kianoush Which wallet are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

For this question to be properly answered you would have to provide more details.

AFAIK the only wallet currently supporting tokens based on ink! is SubWallet (https://subwallet.app). They announced support for PSP-22 and PSP-34 here: https://twitter.com/subwalletapp/status/1596140182796787712.

Those are the two token standards:

- https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-22.md
- https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-34.md

OpenBrush (https://openbrush.io) provides reference implementations for both standards.